# Remove logo from extent report

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

How to remove blue color "Extent" logo from extent report.

Extend report version =3.1.5

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find and edit extent-config.xml, copy and paste the script below over the existing 'scripts' tags.

```
    <scripts>
        <![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.brand-logo.blue.darken-3').css('display','none');
        });
        ]]>
    </scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.logo-content').hide();
    $('.logo-container').html(your Text);
});
```